# Bash if or statement, command not found

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I'm having issues with this line of a shell script:

```
if [ "$(lsb_release -r -s)" == "16.04" ] || [ "$(lsb_release -r -s)" == "17.04" ]; then
```

I get "[: command not found" when running the script. I do not understand why.

```
+ '[' -f /etc/debian_version ']'
++ lsb_release -r -s
+ '[' 17.04 == 16.04 ']'
++ lsb_release -r -s
+ ' [' 17.04 == 17.04 ']'
./mhn/scripts/install_mongo.sh: line 8:  [: command not found
```

I only get the error if running on 17.04, not 16.04. If I switch the statement around and check 17.04 first, it will break on 16.04, and not 17.04. Something in the second half of the statement is breaking.

https://github.com/ngatilio/mhn/blob/2e992934a350e0367a214dc86cc63e7ecd5d59ef/scripts/install_mongo.sh

Comment: Add OS (Ubuntu?)  and bash version to your question.

Comment: Do you still get the same error if you copy-paste that line into a new script, and run that script alone?

Comment: @thatotherguy it works fine if it's just the if statement. But in the full script it's on line 8, and bash is telling me "line 8: [: command not found"

Comment: @d1str0 Can you include the full, unabbreviated output of running the script, including the command you used to run it? It has `set -x` so it should be printing a good chunk of useful output

Comment: @thatotherguy updated

Answer (score 4):

There's your problem:

```
+ ' [' 17.04 == 17.04 ']'
```

You appear to have some kind of funky space character before the last `[`. Delete and retype it to turn it into a regular ascii space.

When you copy-pasted the line here, or when viewing it via the non-raw github view, it's being translated into a regular space, so it's not present in your post. This is also why it works just fine when copy-pasted into another file.

Here's ShellCheck on the file as downloaded (and not copy-pasted) from github:

```
$ shellcheck install_mongo.sh

In install_mongo.sh line 8:
    if [ "$(lsb_release -r -s)" == "16.04" ] || [ "$(lsb_release -r -s)" == "17.04" ]; then
                                               ^-- SC1018: This is a unicode non-breaking space. Delete and retype it.
```

Comment: @d1str0: This illustrates the problem: `cat -A install_mongo.sh | sed -n 8p`

Comment: Wow! Well that was a PITA. Also, shellcheck seems super cool. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if [ "$(lsb_release -r -s)" == "16.04" -o "$(lsb_release -r -s)" == "17.04" ]; then
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately that wouldn't have solved my issued. The other answer solved exactly my issue.